# Can I use twitter api to search tweets one week before?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to search keywords in twitter through tweepy.

However, I found it seems like that I can not search the tweets one week before, the code below is the main search code.

```
for searched_tweets in tweepy.Cursor( API.search,
                                      q = "python", 
                                      since = 2014-02-03, 
                                      until = 2014-02-04, 
                                      lang='en' ).items()
```

I am not sure whether there is any limited or any better way to search by time, thanks for your help!!
:)

Comment: What's not working about that? What error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error message about this code. It can be built, but I can not get any message in this time duration, however, if I change time to 2014-06-03 to 2014-06-04, I can collect all tweets in the new time duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't get tweets older than a week with the twitter search API.

> Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week. - [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

You can get specific tweets older than a week by looking at individual users or using specific post ids (if you have them) but it's not reasonable to index *every single tweet ever* to be searchable using the API.

If you need a large time range, you can collect them yourself using the streaming API or check out a service that does (see this [dev twitter thread](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3619) for examples).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I may need to read more about the twitter API.