# Twitter API query using python Twitter gives few results

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am using Python Twitter to download data from tweets about youTube videos : https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/doc/index.rst

```
def TW():
    return twitter.Api(consumer_key='X',consumer_secret='X',access_token_key='X-X',access_token_secret='X')

for i in TW().GetSearch(term='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftP6Uh_jSUg', count=1000, include_entities=True):
    print('TWEET_URL','twitter.com/'+str(i.user.screen_name)+'/status/'+str(i.id),i.urls,'RETWEETS',i.retweet_count,'USER_MENTIONS',i.user_mentions,'TEXT',i.text,'USER_ID',i.user.id,'USER',i.user.screen_name)
```

When I use GetSearch, I get few results. For example, I get only this one with the previous video query.

```
TWEET_URL twitter.com/Niza_Club/status/740770459030032384 [URL(URL=XX, ExpandedURL=https://youtu.be/ftP6Uh_jSUg)] RETWEETS 0 USER_MENTIONS [User(ID=10228272, ScreenName=YouTube)] TEXT Juniore - A la plage vía @YouTube USER_ID 20470260 USER Niza_Club
```

While the same query done manually on Twitter gives me 15 results, including 5 in the last month : https://twitter.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DftP6Uh_jSUg&src=typd

How can I get the other results ? Is there a better tool that is using Twitter API ? One without it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here : [Can I use twitter api to search tweets one week before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080405/can-i-use-twitter-api-to-search-tweets-one-week-before)

> Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week. - [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).